# Sinon does not seem to spy for an event handler callback

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, sinon

I'm testing a backbone view with Jasmin, Simon and jasmin-simon.

Here is the code:

```
var MessageContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'messages',
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addMessage, this);
    },
    render: function( event ) {
        this.collection.each(this.addMessage);
        return this;
    },
    addMessage: function( message ) {
        console.log('addMessage called', message);
        var view = new MessageView({model: message});
        $('#' + this.id).append(view.render().el);
    }
});
```

Actually, all my tests pass but one. I would like to check that `addMessage` is called whenever I add an item to `this.collection`.

```
describe('Message Container tests', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        this.messageView = new Backbone.View;
        this.messageViewStub = sinon.stub(window, 'MessageView').returns(this.messageView);

        this.message1 = new Backbone.Model({message: 'message1', type:'error'});
        this.message2 = new Backbone.Model({message: 'message2', type:'success'});
        this.messages = new Backbone.Collection([
            this.message1, this.message2            
        ]); 

        this.view = new MessageContainerView({ collection: this.messages });
        this.view.render();

        this.eventSpy = sinon.spy(this.view, 'addMessage');
        this.renderSpy = sinon.spy(this.messageView, 'render');
        setFixtures('<div id="messages"></div>');
    });
    afterEach(function(){
        this.messageViewStub.restore();
        this.eventSpy.restore();
    });

    it('check addMessage call', function(){
        var message = new Backbone.Model({message: 'newmessage', type:'success'});
        this.messages.add(message);

        // TODO: this fails not being called at all
        expect(this.view.addMessage).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
        // TODO: this fails similarly
        expect(this.view.addMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(message, 'Expected to have been called with `message`');
        // these pass
        expect(this.messageView.render).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
        expect($('#messages').children().length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

As you can see `addMessage` is called indeed. (It logs to the console and it calls `this.messageView` as it should. What do I miss in spying for `addMessage` calls?

thanks, Viktor

Comment: Have you tried setting the expectation on the eventSpy instead? `expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();`

Comment: I think I have answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441612/why-is-this-sinon-spy-not-being-called-when-i-run-this-test/9012788#9012788

Answer (score 9):

I'm not quit sure but, as I understand it, the following happens:

1. You create a new view which calls the `initialize` function and bind your `view.addMessage` to your collection.
2. Doing this, Backbone take the function and store it in the event store of your collection.
3. Then you spy on `view.addMessage` which means you overwrite it with a spy function. Doing this will have no effect on the function that is stored in the collection event store.

So their are some problems with your test. You view has a lot of dependencies that you not mock out. You create a bunch of additional Backbone Models and Collections, which means you not test only your view but also Backbones Collection and Model functionality.

You should not test that `collection.bind` will work, but that you have called `bind` on the collection with the parameters `'add', this.addMessage, this`

```
initialize: function() {
    //you dont 
    this.collection.bind('add', this.addMessage, this);
},
```

So, its easy to mock the collection:

```
var messages = {bind:function(){}, each:function(){}}
spyOn(messages, 'bind');
spyOn(messages, 'each');
this.view = new MessageContainerView({ collection: messages });

expect(message.bind).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bind', this.view.addMessage, this.view);

this.view.render()

expect(message.each).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this.view.addMessage);

... and so on
```

Doing it this way you test only your code and have not dependencies to Backbone.

Answer (score 6):

As Andreas said in point 3:

`Then you spy on view.addMessage which means you overwrite it with a spy function. Doing this will have no effect on the function that is stored in the collection event store.`

The direct answer to the question, disregarding all the awesome refactoring Andreas suggested, would be to spy on `MessageContainerView.prototype.addMessage` like so:

```
describe('Message Container tests', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        this.messageView = new Backbone.View;
        this.messageViewStub = sinon.stub(window, 'MessageView').returns(this.messageView);

        this.message1 = new Backbone.Model({message: 'message1', type:'error'});
        this.message2 = new Backbone.Model({message: 'message2', type:'success'});
        this.messages = new Backbone.Collection([
            this.message1, this.message2            
        ]);
        // Here
        this.addMessageSpy = sinon.spy(MessageContainerView.prototype, 'addMessage');
        this.view = new MessageContainerView({ collection: this.messages });
        this.view.render();

        this.eventSpy = sinon.spy(this.view, 'addMessage');
        this.renderSpy = sinon.spy(this.messageView, 'render');
        setFixtures('<div id="messages"></div>');
    });
    afterEach(function(){
        this.messageViewStub.restore();
        MessageContainerView.prototype.addMessage.restore();

    });

    it('check addMessage call', function(){
        var message = new Backbone.Model({message: 'newmessage', type:'success'});
        this.messages.add(message);

        // TODO: this fails not being called at all
        expect(this.addMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
        // TODO: this fails similarly
        expect(this.addMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(message, 'Expected to have been called with `message`');
        // these pass
        expect(this.messageView.render).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
        expect($('#messages').children().length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Regardless, I do recommend implementing Andreas' suggestions. :)