# QUnit, Sinon.js & Backbone unit test frustration: sinon spy appears to fail to detect Backbone Model event callbacks

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, qunit, sinon

In the following unit test code:

```
TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'selection': null
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.on('change:selection', this.doSomething);
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log("Something has been done.");
    }
});

module("Test", {
    setup: function() {
        this.testModel = new TestModel();
    }
});

test("intra-model event bindings", function() {
    this.spy(this.testModel, 'doSomething');
    ok(!this.testModel.doSomething.called);
    this.testModel.doSomething();
    ok(this.testModel.doSomething.calledOnce);
    this.testModel.set('selection','something new');
    ok(this.testModel.doSomething.calledTwice); //this test should past, but fails.  Console shows two "Something has been done" logs.
});
```

The third ok fails, even though the function was effectively called from the backbone event binding, as demo'd by the console.

[image: 3rd test fails]
[image]

This is very frustrating and has shaken my confidence on whether sinon.js is suitable for testing my backbone app.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a problem with how sinon detects whether something has been called?  Is there a workaround?

EDIT: Here's a solution to my specific example, based on the monkey patch method of the accepted answer. While its a few lines of extra setup code in the test itself, (I don't need the module function any more) it gets the job done. Thanks, `mu is too short`

```
test("intra-model event bindings", function() {
    var that = this;
    var init = TestModel.prototype.initialize;
    TestModel.prototype.initialize = function() {
        that.spy(this, 'doSomething');
        init.call(this);
    };

    this.testModel = new TestModel();
    . . . // tests pass!
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `this.spy(this.testModel, 'doSomething')` replaces the `testModel.doSomething` method with a [new wrapper method](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy):

> **var spy = sinon.spy(object, "method");**
>
> Creates a spy for `object.method` and replaces the original method with the spy.

So `this.spy(this.testModel, 'doSomething')` is effectively doing something like this:

```
var m = this.testModel.doSomething;
this.testModel.doSomething = function() {
    // Spying stuff goes here...
    return m.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This means that `testModel.doSomething` is a different function when you bind the event handler in `initialize`:

```
this.bind('change:selection', this.doSomething);
```

than it is after you've attached your spying. The Backbone event dispatcher will call the original `doSomething` method but that one doesn't have the Sinon instrumentation. When you call `doSomething` manually, you're calling the new function that `spy` added and that one does have the Sinon instrumentation.

If you want to use Sinon to test your Backbone events, then you'll have to arrange to have the Sinon `spy` call applied to the model before you bind any event handlers and that probably means hooking into `initialize`.

Maybe you could monkey-patch your model's `initialize` to add the necessary `spy` calls before it binds any event handlers:

```
var init = Model.prototype.initialize;
Model.prototype.initialize = function() {
    // Set up the Spy stuff...
    init.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/C4fnX/1/

You could also try subclassing your model with something like:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var TestModel = Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Set up the Spy stuff...
        Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

And then use `TestModel` instead of Model, this would give you an instrumented version of `Model` in `TestModel` without having to include a bunch of test-specific code inside your normal production-ready `Model`. The downside is that anything else that uses `Model` would need to be subclassed/patched/... to use `TestModel` instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yH3FE/1/

You might be able to get around the `TestModel` problem with:

```
var OriginalModel = Model;
Model = Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Set up the Spy stuff...
        OriginalModel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

but you'd have to get the ordering right to make sure that everyone used the new `Model` rather than the old one.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/u3vgF/1/

Comment: Makes sense. Excellent answer, thanks! At this point, getting the unit tests working on the model itself should be sufficient.  I'll post back if I end up doing something interesting to test callbacks for Views, etc., I'm glad I figured this out early.

Comment: Related question that I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113186/backbone-js-click-event-spy-is-not-getting-called-using-jasmine-js-and-sinon-js

Comment: @Ben: I think monkey patching the `initialize` methods is probably your best bet, that would be fairly low impact and well isolated. I've added some demos to help illustrate the ideas.

Comment: Yep, I updated my test case based on your examples, in the simplest way I could think of, and it worked. See the update to my question, above.

Comment: @Ben: That should work. If you had a collection that used a model and you wanted to spy on both then monkey patching the `initialize` methods would probably be the simplest approach.

Comment: I updated my solved problem to use the monkey path initialize method.  It does seem simpler, I'd just overlooked it when trying it the first time.