# Expect method to have been called is not fulfilled on "onInput" for a contentEditable element

Tags: reactjs, sinon, chai, enzyme, sinon-chai

I have a component that uses `contentEditable` as an input method. The part from the component that is of interest is:

```
<div className="enter-edit-mode" onClick={view.enterEditMode}>
    <div className="user-input" ref="content" contentEditable onInput={view.textChanged}></div>
</div>
```

The component works fine - it gets into the `textChanged` method on user input. The method looks like this:

```
textChanged: function (e) {
    var view      = this,
        textValue = e.target.innerHTML;

    view.setState({
        enteringText: textValue.length,
        temporaryValue: textValue
    });
}
```

**The problem** I'm facing appears when I try to test the input behavior. The setup is done with *enzyme*, *chai*, *sinon*. I'm rendering the component using a simple `renderComponent` function, using enzyme's `mount` method.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    view = renderComponent(card);
    viewReact = view.get(0);
});

it('should enter text changed method on input', function () {
    let spy = sinon.spy(viewReact, 'textChanged');
    view.find('.user-input').simulate('input');
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called;
    spy.restore();
});
```

It outputs *expected textChanged to have been called at least once, but it was never called*. **The weird part** is, however, if I put a `console.log` inside the component's method, it gets there.

**What I've tried to make it work**

- use `sinon.stub` instead of `spy`, as I though that maybe something in my method doesn't work properly
- call it with `view.find('.user-input').simulate('input', {target: {value: "lorem"})` or `.simulate('input', {key: 'a'})`

If instead of simulating the input I do a `viewReact.textChanged()`, it obviously works.

I'm guessing that it's the input method on contentEditable that's causing this. Any suggestions? How can I properly enter text in the `onInput` method? (even if it gets in the `textChanged` method, the text is empty)

Comment: Hmmm, is this solution would resolve your issue? An another SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable)

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo: I've looked into it, and the first problem is that using that means some refactoring of my component and usages. I've given it a try, and I still get the same outcome. I'm also trying right now to directly simulate the `change` event on the `<ContentEditable>` component and still the same, it enters my method but the test crashes.

Comment: Strange are you sure you have found the ('.user-input') ?

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo Yes. I've tried doing a typo with the className and it crashes saying that the element was not found

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I have though before about using `onChange` instead of `onInput` , because I use it on textareas and it works fine and I've managed to also test it. If nothing else shows up here I will do a refactor and try to use onChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue trying to test the following component (which looks similar to yours):

```
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  textChanged(e) { console.log('text changed') },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="enter-edit-mode">
        <div className="user-input" ref="content" contentEditable onInput={ this.textChanged }></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I also managed to get the test working, in a somewhat convoluted way:

```
it('should enter text changed method on input', () => {
  let view = mount(<MyComponent/>);
  let spy  = sinon.spy(view.instance(), 'textChanged');
  view     = view.mount();

  view.find('.user-input').simulate('input');
  expect(spy).to.be.called;
  spy.restore();
});
```

The `view.mount()` to [re-mount](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) the component seems to do the trick here.

I'm wasn't familiar with Enzyme at all (although I like it :), but it looks like it's adding various layers around components, in which case it's easy for Sinon spies to get "lost".

One possible caveat: I did all of this testing in Node using `jsdom`, and not in a browser.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, the `view.mount()` thing really worked. I still can't properly explain it, though. I found a [somewhat similar issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012788/1300817) and I tried moving the spy on the `Card.prototype` before I render the component (s.t. I don't have to use the `mount()` trick) but that didn't work either. I'll leave it like this as it works properly, but it would be nice to properly understand what's happening. In `beforeEach` I'm already mounting the component. Not sure why mounting it again does the trick

Comment: Yeah I can't really explain either (mostly due to lack of knowledge of the specifics of what Enzyme actually does). I also tried spying on the prototype, but because of all the wrapping that's taking place the spy never got called. Spying on the instance made sense, but it wasn't until the re-mount that it actually worked.

Comment: Well, I'm still spying on the `viewReact`, which is kinda a sub-part of the rendered view. I thought that the problem was from there. But on the other hand, similar tests work with the `click` or `change` simulation on other components without the need of re-mounting. That's what I found weird. I guess it's something about how the `input` mechanism gets triggered

Comment: I just found that `view.setState({})` instead of `view.mount()` also works.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little test, I don't have sinon but I found a use case:

```
class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    status: 'default'
  }

  textChanged = () => {
    this.setState({
      status: 'changed'
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="enter-edit-mode" >
          <div className="user-input" ref="content" contentEditable onInput={this.textChanged}>Hello</div>
          <span>{this.state.status}</span>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the test

```
describe('component', () => {
    it('should say changed', () => {
      const component = shallow(<Home />);

      expect(component.find('span').text()).toEqual('default');

      component.find('.user-input').simulate('input', {key: 'a'})

      expect(component.find('span').text()).toEqual('changed');
    });
});
```

It passed all is expected

Comment: This does indeed work, but this also worked for me. I wasn't looking for testing what I end up with in the html, but rather to test that the function was called. As I previously said, I know it was getting called because the functionality worked fine and it printed the `console.logs`, it's just that I wasn't able to make the damn test work properly that got me annoyed enough to post a question

Comment: In all example, and in the enzyme, they give a spy function as prop of the component :(